# Is there a solution with better performance than reshape from long to wide format conversion?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, reshape

I have this small fragment of code to convert a data frame from long to wide.

```
library(reshape2)
mydata <- structure(list(issn = c("1980-4814", "1945-3116", "1681-4835", "1367-0751", "1516-6104", "1359-7566", "2319-0795", "1390-6615", "1808-8023", "1746-4269", "1852-2181", "0022-4596", "1808-2386", "0254-6051", "1981-3686", "1077-2618", "1809-3957", "2179-5746", "0147-6513", "1070-5503"), periodico = c("ABCustos (", "Journal of", "The Electr", "Logic Jour", "DIREITO, E", "REGIONAL &", "REVISTA FÓ", "UMBRAL: RE", "Segurança ", "Journal of", "Augm Domus", "Journal of", "BBR. Brazi", "Jinshu Rèc", "Revista Br", "IEEE Indus", "Revista SO", "Biota Amaz", "Ecotoxicol", "Internatio"), qualis = c("B4", "B3", "B2", "B2", "A1", "B5", "B5", "C ", "B5", "B3", "B3", "A1", "B4", "B3", "B5", "A2", "C ", "B3", "A2", "B1"), area = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L)), .Names = c("issn", "periodico", "qualis", "area"), row.names = c(1L, 501L, 1001L, 1501L, 2001L, 2501L, 3001L, 3501L, 4001L, 4501L, 5001L, 5501L, 6001L, 6501L, 7001L, 7501L, 8001L, 8501L, 9001L, 9501L), class = "data.frame")

reshape(mydata, direction = "wide", 
        idvar = c("issn", "periodico"), 
        timevar = "area")
```

The data 
[image]

and result is

[image]

it's fine, just I want, but as the data frame grows above 2.000 records it gets very slow.

I have only 10 areas to be mapped to columns, but more than 10.000 issn's.

I'm looking for faster ways to achieve the same result.

Thanks

Comment: Use `dcast` from `data.table`.  I think the `dcast` solution was already in the earlier dupe link to similar question posted by you

Comment: @akrun the dcast solution did not work anymore in the way it was supposed to work as I've shown in a similar post elsewhere. It seems due to my limitations with English that something is not clear to you. The answers I found here don't solve the categorical/nominal data problem, they are centered on aggregating numerical values and that is not my case.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work `dcast(setDT(mydata), issn+periodico~area, value.var = "qualis")` gets me similar output as your `reshape` output

Comment: @akrun it's driving me crazy. I got your suggestion with dcast, very fast, but with this extracted small data frame its fine with the original one it gives me dcast(setDT(dfPub), issn+periodico ~ area, value.var = "qualis")
Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'. Running str in both df they show the same structure.

Comment: @akrun maybe something related with encoding, I don't know, but check it out, I get it working fine with relative big slice until dcast(setDT(dataset[1:1789,]), issn+periodico ~ area, value.var = "qualis")  and then it suddenly change it the 1790 record.

Comment: It is because you have duplicate elements in the original data. in that case, you have to make some changes in the code to create a sequence column using `rowid`

Comment: Perhaps try `tidyr::spread` I don't know which of these is faster

Comment: @akrun, Ok, I get it. Duplicated key records starts dcast on data table or reshape to try to count how many of them. Anyway your answer for dcast with Data.Table solved my problem of performance. Shouldn't you leave it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reshaping problems, `dcast` from `data.table` is highly optimized and is very efficient and should be faster than any of the packages currently available

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(mydata), issn+periodico~area, value.var = "qualis")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(area = paste('qualis',area,sep=".")) %>% 
  spread(area, qualis)
```